# What is the equivalent of xset led 3?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, wayland

I am using gnome on wayland on arch. I used to start my keyboards leds with xset led 3. How can this be accomplished while using wayland?

Answer (score 4):

I also struggled with this and finally came up with a solution:

https://gist.github.com/ps1dr3x/b15c62eafb388ddf8bb7d3896d1a1cee

Basically you can turn on/off the keyboard backlight by changing the brightness value in /sys/class/leds/`input`/brightness

e.g.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/input0::scrolllock/brightness'
```

**P.s. `input` might be different**

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however requiring root is not ideal.

Comment: I definitely hope that soon there'll be another way to do this, but for now I've set a root cronjob at boot. This way backlight is always on, but not all users needs to have root permissions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggested script to switch the keyboard lights on and off under Wayland.

It finds the proper path then uses it with the command provided by @Michele above.

```
#!/bin/bash
pathbeginswith=$(find /sys/class/leds -iname "*scrolllock")
completepath="$pathbeginswith/brightness"
if test "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ; then
    sudo "$0" "$1"
    exit $?
fi
value=`sudo cat $completepath`
if [ $value -eq 0 ]
then
   sudo echo '1' > $completepath
else
   sudo echo '0' > $completepath
fi
```

Please note I only have one keyboard with backlight connected, this could need tweaking if there are more than one, etc.

This script requires sudo. I called it "kbdwaylandleds" and stored it in /usr/local/bin.

Appending the following line to /etc/sudoers enables its usage without a sudo password:

usernameXXX ALL = NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/kbdwaylandleds

That way it can be added to gnome as a user script on session start for usernameXXX, and/or assigned to a keyboard shortcut.